# Unable to correctly write data in a text file

Tags: c

I wrote the following program to print 200 random number in a file:

```
int main() 
{
    FILE * fp; 
    fp = fopen ( "myfile.txt", "w" ) ;
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf ( "Unable to create file." ) ;
        exit ( 0 ) ;
    }

    int i, noofr=200, j ; 

    for ( i = 0 ; i < noofr ; i++ )
    {
        j = rand ()%100 ;
        fwrite ( &j, sizeof ( int ), 1, fp ) ;
        printf ( "%d\t", j ) ;
    }

    fclose ( fp ) ;

    printf ( "\nFile is created. \nPress any key to continue." ) ;

    return 0;

}
```

On the console the number are printing correctly, but in the file, I see:

> )   C   "       E      N   :   >   @      -   Q      =   [   _   * 
>      $   [         5   \   R            _   /      G   &   E
>   C   c   #   ^            !   I   @   )      5   D   /   ,   >   9 
>   %   ;      )      N      #   Z   *   X      (   *   @   0   .
>   Z      F   2         ]   0         T   6   8   (   B   L
>   ,   '         %   &      R      )   !      '   :         M
>   I   V      -      H   F      M   I   a      V   Z   =   $   7   C 
>   7   J      4   2   2   )      B         [      %   9   W   5   S 
>   -            :      X      .             D       [   >   7       ;      %   0   S   _   )      2   [   $   J      `      0   c   D   T 
>   Q   "   5   c      &       X      C      ]   0   S

I am running the above program on windows 7 32 bit with visual studio 2010.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Use `fprintf` instead of `fwrite` to write to file.

Comment: @Rohan yes , it worked, by what is wrong with fwrite ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite

Comment: `fprintf` formats the values it must output as indicated by the format string, but most importantly, it formats it as text (which is what you want). `fwrite` doesn't do any interpretation of what it must output, it just considers it as a stream of bytes. You could for instance use `sprintf` to obtain a textual representation of your ints, and then use `fwrite` to save it to disk in that format.

Answer (score 1):

The `fwrite` function writes a *chunk of memory* to a file and your chunk of memory in this case is an integer in *binary* form. For example, the decimal integer `314,159` (`4CB2F16`) in 32-bit big-endian format would be stored in memory as the hex digits:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 00 | 04 | CB | 2F |
+----+----+----+----+
```

So writing that memory block to a file will generally not result in anything readable by a human, unless you have an unusual number like `1348565002` or `175661392` (depending on the endian-ness).

In order to write your integer in human-readable format, you just use `fprintf`, *very* similar to the way you used it to print to standard output:

```
fprintf (fp, "%d\t", j);
printf ("%d\t", j ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with the fact that *you have used* the **fwrite** function instead of the **fprintf** function.

The fwrite function is a function commonly used to write binary data into a file. The data which we read in a file is generally ASCII. ASCII text uses 1 byte (8 bits or 8 0/1 places to fill) to represent each character. Now when you put binary data into a file you are placing 1's or 0's one by one into the file.

Now when you opened the file each of the 1's and 0's got converted into their corresponding ASCII value.

To use the fprintf function, it is exactly similar to the printf function: 
`fprintf(fp,"%d",j);`

If you wish for more info:

http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-reference/fwrite-function/

http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-reference/fprintf-function/